# Erdős-Szekeres game

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

Given $n$. Two players in turn mark points on the plane. No three may be collinear, no $n$ may form a convex $n$-gon. The player who does not have legal move loses. Who has a winning strategy?

Comment: For $n=3,4$ the second player has a winning strategy. Have you checked any bigger $n$ by hand?

Comment: The game is parametrized by $n$, presumably, as in the theorem.

Comment: Unless there is a generic argument like strategy stealing (which doesn't work in this case), this is likely to be a difficult question. It might be more fruitful to consider how long the game lasts. The Erdős-Szekeres theorem gives some bound but it might be possible to improve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was raised and discussed in Parikshit Kolipaka and Sathish Govindarajan, Two player game variant of the Erdős-Szekeres problem, Discrete Math. Theor. Comput. Sci. 15 (2013), no. 3, 73–100, MR3141828. It says the second player wins for $n=5$.